# Print a key in a PHP multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, syntax, echo

I have a multidimensional array and I want to print the contents as follows:

```
Sam
class1: 76
class2: 62
class3: 56
class4: 60

Matt
class1: 76
class2: 62
class3: 56
class4: 60

Dave
class1: 76
class2: 62
class3: 56
class4: 60

Steve
class1: 76
class2: 62
class3: 56
class4: 60
```

My problem is that I don't know how to refer to the key of the first sub-array (the names). `key($index)` just replaces all of the names in the output with "class1". Here's my code so far:

```
$scoreList = array(
    "Sam" => array(
        "class1" => 76,
        "class2" => 62,
        "class3" => 56,
        "class4" => 60,
        ),
    "Matt" => array(
        "class1" => 76,
        "class2" => 62,
        "class3" => 56,
        "class4" => 60,
        ),
    "Dave" => array(
        "class1" => 76,
        "class2" => 62,
        "class3" => 56,
        "class4" => 60,
        ),
    "Steve" => array(
        "class1" => 76,
        "class2" => 62,
        "class3" => 56,
        "class4" => 60,
        ));

printGrade($scoreList["Sam"]);
printGrade($scoreList["Matt"]);
printGrade($scoreList["Dave"]);
printGrade($scoreList["Steve"]);

function printGrade($index) {
    Print key($index)."<br>";
    for($i = 1; $i <= 4; $i++)
    {
        Print "class".$i.": ".$index["class".$i]."<br>";
    };
    echo "<br>";
}
```

I'm pretty new to web development, so if anyone has any hints I'd really appreciate it!

Edit: Am I getting closer...?

```
function printGrade($index) {
        foreach ($index as &$value) {
        print array_keys($index).": ".$value."<br>";
    }
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Comment: Please learn how to use a [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop!

Comment: @Rizier123 Am I getting closer...? I've added a `foreach` loop to the bottom of the post but it still doesn't work as intended...

Comment: why do so many people have to be aasshats instead of helping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this :

```
foreach($scoreList as $key => $val)
{
    echo $key."</br>";
    foreach( $val as $keyItem => $valKey)
    {
        echo $keyItem ." : ".$valKey."</br>";
    }
}
```

Out put:

```
Sam
class1 : 76
class2 : 62
class3 : 56
class4 : 60
Matt
class1 : 76
class2 : 62
class3 : 56
class4 : 60
Dave
class1 : 76
class2 : 62
class3 : 56
class4 : 60
Steve
class1 : 76
class2 : 62
class3 : 56
class4 : 60
```

Comment: Brilliant! It works perfectly. I didn't even know `foreach` loops existed until five minutes ago, I'll use them all the time now! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with a recursive function call:

```
function printGrade($scoreList) {
    foreach($scoreList as $key=>$score) {
        echo $key;
        if(is_array($score)) {
            echo "<br/>";
            printGrade($score);
        } else {
            echo ": $score<br/>";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php

$scoreList = array(
    "Sam" => array(
        "class 1" => 76,
        "class 2" => 62,
        "class 3" => 56,
        "class 4" => 60,
        ),
    "Matt" => array(
        "class 1" => 76,
        "class 2" => 62,
        "class 3" => 56,
        "class 4" => 60,
        ),
    "Dave" => array(
        "class 1" => 76,
        "class 2" => 62,
        "class 3" => 56,
        "class 4" => 60,
        ),
    "Steve" => array(
        "class 1" => 76,
        "class 2" => 62,
        "class 3" => 56,
        "class 4" => 60,
        ));

 echo "Sam: ". "<br>"."<br>";
 echo "class 1:&nbsp&nbsp". $scoreList ['Sam'] ['class 1']. "<br>";
 echo "class 2:&nbsp&nbsp". $scoreList ['Sam'] ['class 2']. "<br>";
 echo "class 3:&nbsp&nbsp". $scoreList ['Sam'] ['class 3']. "<br>";
 echo "class 4:&nbsp&nbsp". $scoreList ['Sam'] ['class 4']. "<br>"."<br>";

 echo "Matt: ". "<br>"."<br>";
 echo "class 1:&nbsp&nbsp". $scoreList ['Matt'] ['class 1']. "<br>";
 echo "class 2:&nbsp&nbsp". $scoreList ['Matt'] ['class 2']. "<br>";
 echo "class 3:&nbsp&nbsp". $scoreList ['Matt'] ['class 3']. "<br>";
 echo "class 4:&nbsp&nbsp". $scoreList ['Matt'] ['class 4']. "<br>"."<br>";

 echo "Dav: ". "<br>"."<br>";
 echo "class 1:&nbsp&nbsp". $scoreList ['Dave'] ['class 1']. "<br>";
 echo "class 2:&nbsp&nbsp". $scoreList ['Dave'] ['class 2']. "<br>";
 echo "class 3:&nbsp&nbsp". $scoreList ['Dave'] ['class 3']. "<br>";
 echo "class 4:&nbsp&nbsp". $scoreList ['Dave'] ['class 4']. "<br>"."<br>";

 echo "Steve: ". "<br>"."<br>";
 echo "class 1:&nbsp&nbsp". $scoreList ['Steve'] ['class 1']. "<br>";
 echo "class 2:&nbsp&nbsp". $scoreList ['Steve'] ['class 2']. "<br>";
 echo "class 3:&nbsp&nbsp". $scoreList ['Steve'] ['class 3']. "<br>";
 echo "class 4:&nbsp&nbsp". $scoreList ['Steve'] ['class 4']. "<br>"."<br>";

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, including an explanation of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

Using only **one foreach** with echo out all inner arrays *(`$val`)* as `key: value` pairs, using `implode(glue, pieces)` which *glue* is `</br>` new line. To print `key: value`, I used `array_map` with callback `fn` return format `$k: $v`, which `$k` and `$v` are from `array_keys` and `array_values` respectively.

```php
foreach($scoreList as $key => $val)
{
    echo $key."</br>";
    echo implode("</br>", array_map(
        fn($k,$v)=>"$k: $v", 
        array_keys($val),
        array_values($val)
      )
    );
    echo "</br></br>";
}
```

**Output* as you *Expect**

```
Sam
class1: 76
class2: 62
class3: 56
class4: 60

Matt
class1: 76
class2: 62
class3: 56
class4: 60

Dave
class1: 76
class2: 62
class3: 56
class4: 60

Steve
class1: 76
class2: 62
class3: 56
class4: 60
```